# $\|P_X-P_Y\|_2=\|(1-P_Y)P_X\|_2$

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, projection-matrices, grassmannian

Let $X,Y$ be two linear subspace of the same dimension of a finite linear space.
Denote by $\|\cdot\|_2$ the induced matrix norm. The question asks me to prove the following, as written in title.
$$\|P_X-P_Y\|_2=\|(1-P_Y)P_X\|_2$$

where $P_{X}$ refers to the projection operator which satisfy $(P_X)^*=P_X=(P_X)^2$ and $\text{image}(P_X)=X$.

As far as I consider, the projection matrices are Hermitian, thus it can be written in diagonal form $P_X=UAU^*,\,P_Y=VBV^*$.
Furthermore, since they're of the same dimension, we can assume $A=B=L$ is the diagonal matrix whose first $k$ diagonal element is $1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Notice $$P_X-P_Y=(1-P_Y)P_X-P_Y(1-P_X):=A+B$$ where the two matrices are orthogonal to each other, $A^*B=B^*A=0$.

$$\|P_X-P_Y\|_2=\|(1-P_Y)P_X\|_2\lor\|P_Y(1-P_X)\|_2$$

It's now equivalent to prove
$$\|(1-P_Y)P_X\|_2\geq \|P_Y(1-P_X)\|_2$$

With the decomposition of Hermitians, it's equivalent to verify
$$\|LW(I-L)\|_2\geq \|LW^*(I-L)\|_2$$

where $W=U^*V$.

It seems in fact the inequality should hold as an equality. But I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Note that $\|(I-P_Y)P_X\|_2=\|(P_X-P_Y)P_X\|_2\leq \|P_X-P_Y\|_2$. And, you have already shown that $\|P_X-P_Y\|_2\geq \|(1-P_Y)P_X\|_2$. This completes the proof.

Comment: And, a similar argument also shows that $\|P_X-P_Y\|_2=\|P_Y(1-P_X)\|_2$. From this it follows that indeed $\|(1-P_Y)P_X\|_2=\|P_Y(1-P_X)\|_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $$A:=LW(I-L),\, B:=(I-L)WL$$ can be considered as submatrices of the unitary matrix $W$.

Denote $C=LWL$. We have $$AA^*=L-CC^*,\, B^*B=L-C^*C$$ where $L$ is the identity map of subspace spanned by first $k$ columns, which is sufficient to deduce $AA^*,B^*B$ share the eigenvalues, to be explicit, $\sqrt{1-\sigma^2(C)}$, and $A,\,B$ share the singular values (other than mutilpicity of $0$ to be rigorous).